# Проблема с компиляцией файла из .py в .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, nuitka

Вообще я делал приложение с некоторыми зависимыми файлами и после этого хотел из 3 файлов .py сделать один .exe пытался и через Nuitka и Pyinstaller и auto-py-to-exe. Не получилось :(
[image: Та ошибка, которая не даёт даже открыть приложение]